# PostgreSQL functions INSERT bad performance vs raw SQL INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance

I'm trying to make a function in PostgreSQL to insert data. My request is very simple, when I execute the SQL request outside of the function I have great performance, but when it's inside a function, performance are terrible.

When I do :

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE INSERT INTO car (name) VALUES ('test') RETURNING *;
```

I have great performance ( Execution time: 0.054 ms ), that's normal it's just a simple insert request.

But then if I move to a function created like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createCar(_name text) 
RETURNS SETOF car AS $$
    INSERT INTO car (name) VALUES (_name) RETURNING *;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

I execute the function like this :

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM createCar('test');
```

And performance are terrible ( like 10 times slower, ~ Execution time: 1.126 ms ). And that's just a simple insert !

For a simple SELECT function moving to a 'STABLE' function solved the problem, but for an insert I can just be in 'VOLATILE' mode because I'm modifying the database...

I may be doing something wrong, thanks for your help!

Comment: Not an answer, but some aspects to consider: Being wrapped in a function, the simple insert entails building and populating data structures accessible from pl/pgsql,so some overhead is to be expected. Moreover, as long as you don't use it and there is no update on the table, the result set of the sql insert does not need to be materialized. Strictly speaking that holds for a funciton too, but most certainly the language implementation does not support lazy evaluation of return arguments (that's only informed guessing, though)

Comment: I found an interesting explanation here : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58365

Comment: Function overhead, yes. We should actually define what "terrible" is. 20x slower is not what's going on. There's a constant cost of marshaling, which is probably in the 1ms range. That constant cost is per invocation, regardless of how much or how little work is actually being done.